# Use Quasar App code in background script of BEX

Tags: javascript, typescript, quasar-framework, quasar

I am developing a browser extension using Quasar framework's BEX mode. In the app part (popup window), I have a TypeScript file which contains some common functions used throughout the application.

I want to use the same function in `background.js` in order to avoid code duplication. So to do that I simple imported them on top of the file but when I run the extension I get some errors in the console of background script.

#### Logger.ts

```
export function appendDebugMessage(message: string) {
    console.log(message)
}
```

#### backgound.js

```
let logger = require ("src/utilities/Logger.ts");
logger.appendDebugMessage("from background script")
```

For the above code, I get the error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

If I use `import` instead of `require`

```
import {appendDebugMessage} from "src/utilities/Logger";
appendDebugMessage("from background script")
```

I get the error:

> SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

This is a very basic example but I have a lot of code involving native messaging stuff that I would like to reuse.

So, my question is, how can I re-use the code for my background script? Or is it not possible at all and I need to re-write the TS code in JS again for backgrouns script?

Answer (score 0):

You can put multiple scripts in the background_scripts section of the manifest.json.
All the scripts will be loaded into the same global environment.